# Why does GoogleDrive Update API return a 500 error (Unknown Error)?

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

GoogleDrive update API returns a 500 error.
This error occurs when calling with the title in the request body.

We are sending a request as follows:

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{fileId}

Authorization: Bearer {Authorization}
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=25266828
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Length: 140

--25266828
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{"title":"renamed_name.jpg"}

--25266828--
```

The message included the following wording.

```
[Internal Server Error] [Unknown Error]
```

We first detected this issue on June 14th.
Previously it worked fine and I haven't changed the source code.
Has there been any change?

Comment: This is an internal server error, which means it's on Google's side. These are usually resolved quickly, though if you have a way to reliably reproduce this error, then please share it.

Comment: We have added information about the request that causes this issue.
I contacted google, but it didn't reproduce and it was our problem.
Is there something wrong?

Comment: You'll need to find a way to reproduce it. Can you give full instructions on how to do it?